# How to define function return type of a custom object literal

Tags: typescript

Here is the object, which is returned from a method in a class:

```
public dbParameters() // HERE
{
    return {
        "values": this.valuesForDb,
        "keys": this.keysForDb,
        "numbers": this.numberOfValues,
    }
}
```

Could you please advise how to define the type of the function return, in this case ? Or maybe this is not the proper way to do it and I should use another type instead of the object literal ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way could be just a message, that result is a dictinary:

```
public dbParameters() : { [key: string]: any}
{
    return {
        "values": this.valuesForDb,
        "keys": this.keysForDb,
        "numbers": this.numberOfValues,
    }
}
```

The other could use some interface

```
export interface IResult {
    values: any[];
    keys: string[];
    numbers: number[];
}


export class MyClass
{
    public dbParameters() : IResult
    {
        return {
            values: this.valuesForDb,
            keys: this.keysForDb,
            numbers: this.numberOfValues,
        }
    }
}
```

With `interface` we have big advantage... it could be reused on many places *(declaration, usage...)* so that would be the preferred one

And also, we can compose most specific setting of the properties result

```
export interface IValue {
   name: string;
   value: number;
}
export interface IResult {
    values: IValue[];
    keys: string[];
    numbers: number[];
}
```

Play with [that here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aexport%20class%20MyClass%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09public%20dbParameters()%20%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22values%22%3A%20this.valuesForDb%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22keys%22%3A%20this.keysForDb%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22numbers%22%3A%20this.numberOfValues%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20IResult%20%7B%0D%0A%09values%3A%20any%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09keys%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09numbers%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20class%20MyClass2%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%09public%20dbParameters()%20%3A%20IResult%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20this.valuesForDb%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20keys%3A%20this.keysForDb%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20numbers%3A%20this.numberOfValues%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Superb answer thanks, I will go with the interface solution. Do you suggest putting interfaces into a single file for entire project, or on per sub apps of the project ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. Interfaces should be extracted *(not only one file, but could be even more - per logical structure)* ... so, we do have few of them for example - and we try to keep them grouped by modules, types...